# Dealing with the same NSNotification in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the below notifications to reload `ViewControllerA` when my app comes back from background mode. It works correctly, but the `applicationEnteredForeground:` method gets called every time when I open the app again. For example if I close the app when `ViewControllerB` or  `ViewControllerC` is on the screen and open it again the method will be called despite the `viewDidLoad` of `ViewControllerB` doesn't contain `applicationEnteredForeground:` method. I would like to know that how could solve this issue? My goal is to use `applicationEnteredForeground:` only when `ViewControllerA` was on the screen before I closed the app. 
As a possible solution I would just remove the `NSNotificationCenter` in the `viewDidDisappear`, but since the observer is in the `viewDidLoad` it won't work when the user navigates back, because `viewDidLoad` won't be called again. Is there any fix for this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationEnteredForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

- (void)applicationEnteredForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {

  // do stuff...

}
```

Comment: As a thumb rule, if you want to catch `NSNotification`s only when a view controller is active, you add the observer in it's `viewWillAppear:`/`viewDidAppear:` and remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear:`/`viewDidDisappear:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a view controller is on screen by checking the window property of it's view. It will work in most standard cases.

```
- (void)applicationEnteredForeground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.view.window == nil) {
        // Not on screen
        return;
    }

    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: self.view.window == nil is a bad way to check if the window is on screen. It doesn't even check that, it could be hidden, but the memory allocated. Use instead the NSWindow [-occlusionstate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/occlusionState) to check if any part of the window is visible.

Comment: This is iOS, not OS X, things are a bit different.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't see the tags :D

Answer (score 2):

You should remove ViewController A's event listener on viewWillDisappear and add it in viewWillAppear. That way, VC A will only be listening when it is the visible view controller.

Comment: also, you can triple check by using the NSWindow's -[occlusionState](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/occlusionState)